# Are $T_1^{-1}T_3$ and $T_1 T_3^{-1}$ in $Br_4$ conjugate?

Tags: group-theory

Let $Br_n$ be the braid group generated by $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_{n-1}$ subject to the relations $ T_i T_j T_i = T_j T_i T_j $ if $|i-j|=1$ and $T_i T_j = T_j T_i$ if $|i-j|>1$.

Are $T_1^{-1}T_3$ and $T_1 T_3^{-1}$ in $Br_4$ conjugate?

We have $(T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2) T_1 (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2)^{-1} = T_3$ and $(T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2) T_1^{-1} (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2)^{-1} = T_3^{-1}$. But I didn't find $g \in Br_4$ such that $g T_1^{-1} T_3 g^{-1} = T_1 T_3^{-1}$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
\begin{align}
& (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2) T_3 T_1^{-1} (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2)^{-1} \\
& = T_1 (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2) T_1^{-1} (T_2 T_1 T_3 T_2)^{-1} \\
& = T_1 T_3^{-1}.
\end{align}